# Continuous Touch detection in imageView using Touch event..?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I have a method which  call the another view. i want to call this method after the image is continuously for a definite time.

This type of method found in UIButton  = touchDown(),touchup().

Is there any method in touch event to find continuous touch in image view.

Pls help me.

thanks in advance

Comment: Use a gesture recognizer

Answer (score 0):

You can use these events for UIIMAGEVIEW:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Comment: Thanks, But this methods finds only touch in the image view. I'm trying to detect the continuous touch on the image view. Like in UIButton touchdown() method.

Comment: touchesBegan and touchesEnd are the events only

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to count the touch (continous like double tap)

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

int index =[touch view].tag;

if (touch.tapCount == number && index == imageTag) {

}

}
```

tapCount will be the count of tap in continues time with a very short time interval (double tap). you cannot use it if the count of tap you want to watch has longer delay (say 5 single taps). alternatively, you can remember the touches for your imageview,  something like:

```
 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
      UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
      int index =[touch view].tag;

      if(index == imagetag){
         if([tempMutableArray count] < definiteTime){
            [tempMutableArray addObject:@"any"]
           }else{ 
            [tempMutablArray removeAllObjects]; 
            //you can call the method now
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: What is "tempMutableArray" here..??

Comment: its a instance of NSMutableArray that supposed to be in the header file. the code is meant to just to give you an idea, gesture recognizer is an option  too

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tap gesture which you can see the answer i wrote in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355671/how-do-i-implement-the-uitapgesturerecognizer-into-my-program/11355713#11355713) thread.In this you can set the number of taps which needs to fire the event.Hope this helps you.