# Use app background as button

Tags: ios, uibutton

I want a certain function to activate when the user taps anywhere on the app, and I have no idea how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Add UITapGestureRecognizer to the view of your view controller?

Comment: Noob here, Not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ray Wenderlich has great iOS articles.  I would work through his UIGestureRecognizer example:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more

And StackOverFlow usually has great explanations too.  For example:

[How do I implement the UITapGestureRecognizer into my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355671/how-do-i-implement-the-uitapgesturerecognizer-into-my-application)

Comment: Thanks, I did not know what this was called, will check this out.

Comment: Worked great! Thanks so much!