# Detect a touch down event immediately on bottom's area in IOS7

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7

In IOS7 application,Touch down event in bottom's area(being related to control center) is not triggered immediately.

- down event is not triggered when touch down.
- down event is triggered when touch move.

I know that it's not a bug and features in IOS7.

But, I believe there is some solutions for it.

Comment: try like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355671/how-do-i-implement-the-uitapgesturerecognizer-into-my-application).

Comment: I've already tested it with GestureReconizer. But Tap gestures is reconized when touch up.

Comment: I resolved it throughout triggering event. But to do something like that without any problems, it's needed to understand design concept.

Comment: I solved it as doing sub touchesBegan.