# trying to add a UITapGestureRecognizer but not working

Tags: ios, ios7, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have tried setting up a simple UITapGestureRecognizer on a UILabel but it is not working. Nothing seems to be recognized and nothing is written to the log.

in a method called from viewDidLoad

```
  UILabel *miTN = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 100, 150, 15)];
  [miTN setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapRecognized)];
  [miTN addGestureRecognizer: tapRecognizer];
  [miView addSubview:miTN];

   ... later

  - (void)tapRecognized:(id)sender
  {
    NSLog(@"that tap was recognized");
  }
```

Also, this is called in response to an async network call. Could that be causing the problem? Is there some other issue that might be causing isssue?  I'm not really sure what first step to debug would be - I checked Color Blended Layers to see if they were ovrelapping but don't appear to be.

Comment: What type of view is `miView`? Are you seeing the view on the screen? If it's an iPhone in portrait, you've got its origin horizontally aligned 20px from the right side of the screen.

Comment: it is just a UIView - one possible issue is that this code exists in a callback block but I think it shoudl be retained correclty. The label get written just fine in the simulator.

Comment: Are any other gestures being added to it or any parent views?

Comment: I don't think so - I am investigating that now. I was thinking it was just some stupid syntax mistake on my part originally but thinking now it's some kind of unanticipated interaction.

Answer (score 1):

You should add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to the protocol list for your viewcontroller class

```
@interface TSViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

and insert string:

```
tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

and replace

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapRecognized)];
```

to

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapRecognized:)];
```

Comment: Are you sure that's necessary? The OP isn't using any delegate methods.

Comment: you can try. i'm sure.

Comment: @sooper about delegate you can read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355671/how-do-i-implement-the-uitapgesturerecognizer-into-my-application

Comment: It would still work without setting the delegate and implementing the protocol as you're setting a target (`self`) for the action. Read the last comment posted for the solution of that question you've linked.

Answer (score 0):

in Swift, you have to enable by doing this as follows.
        yourLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true