# Tap gesture not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am developing an app in which user can add some icons like hat, hair on the captured picture.For this I have a image view on the screen to hold the captured image and below this I have a scrollview to display various icons that user can apply. 
When I tap any icon placed inside the scroll view, I need to move this icon to the center captured picture, but when I tried it with code this sets the image to the center of the scroll view not the entire view.
But when I remove the scroll view and put the image outside the image view this works. Please suggest.

//In view Did Load

```
//*************************************adding gusture******************************
    //SINGLETAP
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGestureRecognizer_For_image15 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTapAction_For_Image_15:)];
    singleTapGestureRecognizer_For_image15.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.image_15 addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer_For_image15];
    //DOUBLE TAP
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGestureRecognizer_For_image15 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTapAction_For_Image_15:)];
    doubleTapGestureRecognizer_For_image15.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.image_15 addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGestureRecognizer_For_image15];
    //End Image 15








//***********************************Handling Tap
//SIngle TAP

-(void)handleSingleTapAction_For_Image_15:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)handleSingleTapAction_For_Image_15{
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(250.0, 250.0);
    CGPoint currentCenter = self.view.center;
    self.image_15.frame = CGRectMake(self.image_15.frame.origin.x, self.image_15.frame.origin.y, newSize.width, newSize.height);
    self.image_15.center = currentCenter;
}

//Double Tap
-(void)handleDoubleTapAction_For_Image_15:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)doubleTapGestureRecognizer_For_image15
{
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0);
    CGPoint currentCenter = self.view.center;
    self.image_15.frame = CGRectMake(self.image_15.frame.origin.x, self.image_15.frame.origin.y, newSize.width, newSize.height);
    self.image_15.center = currentCenter;
}
```

Comment: Is this code from ViewController or a different class?

Comment: To be add tapgestuer you have to refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355671/how-do-i-implement-the-uitapgesturerecognizer-into-my-application

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the center of the image from the self.view's center but I think you also have to take care of the scrollview frame offset from origin. So your `image_15` center should be set like

`self.image_15.center = CGPointMake(currentCenter.x-yourScrollView.frame.origin.x, currentCenter.y-yourScrollView.frame.origin.y);`
(provided scrollview is also a direct subview of `self.view`)

I can refine my answer if you provide me details about your view hierarchy incode.