# TouchesBegan with 2 fingers

Tags: objective-c

I want to track user touches on screen. the user can touch with two fingers and then remove 1 Or touch with one finger and immediately with another (there will be two fingers currently on the screen) then remove one finger. How to exactly track the touch 1 and touch 2

Comment: Since the user can swipe on the screen which calls touchesmoved, the touches are changing randomly. Is there a way I can the touches in the right order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you mean by saying "remove 1 Or touch with one finger and immediately with another." I assume what you're looking for is to track multiple touches. If so, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43435058/6109712).

The basic concept for this is to store each UITouch ID in an array when `touchesBegan::` called, and later compare each ID with the touches on screen on `touchesMoved::` event. This way, each finger can be paired with a single object, and be tracked along when panning.

If you only want to track two fingers, simply set `MAX_TOUCHES` to 2. Hope this helped.

Comment: Both fingers are moved and the user takes one finger off the screen. How would I know if it is touch 1 or 2?

Comment: Use `NSArray *allTouches = [touches allObjects];` to get the touches with a certain event, and then `UITouch *touch = allTouches[i];` to get the touch you want to track. You would probably want to save it in a variable for later comparison to identify which touch it is.

Comment: my requirement is for 2 fingers. User can swipe with both Fingers or (one finger is moving and other is stationary) or When swiping, the user would remove one finger (Here i want to exactly know which finger got removed)

Comment: So what kind of result do you want to achieve? Panning, swiping, pinching, or tapping? Make sure you know the difference between these gestures.

Comment: I am developing a keyboard for iOS.

Comment: 1. If user touches at one point and ends at the same point, consider it as a tap 2. If the user touches at one point and moves to the next letter (in keyboard from A to s) then consider it as swipe. Both the actions can happen simultaneously (while swiping on the left side of the keyboard, the user can tap a letter on the right. I want to exactly track which finger is moved/tapped/removed

Comment: OK, I think I understand. So you want to handle two different kind of gestures, a pan and a tap, correct? (Swipe usually refers to four directions: up, down, left, right, as shown [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiswipegesturerecognizerdirection). For "any" direction, I would call it a "pan".)

Comment: Now this would be much easier to handle than tracking multi-touches. All you have to do is to create a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and a `UITapGestureRecognizer`, and then use this delegate shown [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624208-gesturerecognizer?language=objc) to make them work simultaniously. How to track exactly "which finger?" Just handle the two gesture recognizers separately, as answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11355713/6109712).

Comment: I kind of modified your code http://stackoverflow.com/a/43435058/6109712 . Is there a to know that there are no touches on the screen? i believe that would solve the problem

Comment: You can try creating an integer that counts the number of touches on screen. Add the number of `[[touches allObjects] count]` to the counter on `touchesBegan`, and subtract the number of `[[touches allObjects] count]` on `touchesEnded` and `touchesCancelled`. Tell me how it goes:)